# Why does my browser not open up a URL that is just an image?

Tags: browser, images

Sometimes when I view an image (just an image, something like  `http://www.example.com/blah.jpg`), it sometimes opens up the image and other times I am asked which program I want to use to view the file.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually configured on the host site.

Sometimes the host wants to force the download as shown in this example [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/233/force-file-download-for-known-file-types/).

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with the mime-type being sent by the web-server not matching the extension for that mimeType on your computer.

Poke around:

```
HKCR\MIME\Database\Content Type
```

i don't know the specifics. i've looked into it a few times in the past; but i've forgotten.

But it can be the fault of a mis-configured web-server; sending you a .jpg when with a Content-Type of image/gif.